# Custom Cloudwatch Log Group for Glue job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I have AWS GLUE Python application by default logs are available in Cloudwatch Log Group `/aws-glue/jobs/output` and `/aws-glue/jobs/error` for `stdout` and `stderr` respectively. I have explored AWS documentations and several websites for the process to redirect logs to a custom Cloudwatch Log Group like `/dev/<app_name>/`, but no luck. If any one has idea over this, please share the process.

Comment: Do you use a Python script or so, to perform the job? And also please tell more about what you've tried so that people would not come up with what you've already tried.

Comment: Yes using a Python script. Unfortunately until now could not find any option to achieve this. I'm worrying even if this is possible.

Comment: Couldn't find any direct option. Workaround used cloudwatch event (glue job state change) with Lambda target. Segregated the logs based on event and job name, saved to s3.

Answer (score 2):

for spark type glue jobs you can enable continuous logging but for a python shell type glue job continuous logging is not available , therefore you will not be able to create a custom log group for that, but there is a workaround for this. refer below for more info

[How to use a CloudWatch custom log group with Python Shell Glue job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61625190/how-to-use-a-cloudwatch-custom-log-group-with-python-shell-glue-job)